# In Python how do I use a for loop, to create nested list from dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop, nested

This is homework:

```
fruits = {'banana':3,'apple':2, 'mango':1, 'kiwi':5}
```

This is the result I'm supposed to get:

```
fruits_list = [
    ['banana', 'banana', 'banana'], 
    ['apple', 'apple'], 
    ['mango'], 
    ['kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi']]
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what have you tried?

Comment: what I had tried was more like:

Comment: fruits_list = [key*value for key, value in fruits.items()]

Comment: Check posted answer. You're close but, in order to get a list with repeated items, you need to pass a list. Do `[key]*value`. If you just do `key*value` you'll get a string concatenation, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate all over fruits keys and build a list repeating the key `N=value` times.

You can accomplish this with a **list comprehension**.

- To iterate all over dict items you'll need `fruits.items()`.
- To build a list repeating each key N times do: `[key]*N`.
- As dict values indicate how many times to repeat, do: `[key]*value`.

Finally:

```
fruits_list = [[key]*value for key, value in fruits.items()]
```

Then `print(fruit_list)` gives you:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

[['banana', 'banana', 'banana'], ['apple', 'apple'], ['mango'], ['kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi']]
```